Does TCP Keep Alive stop keep alive probes if there is any activity on the connection?
I am currently trying to enable TCP Keep Alive support for my application. I understand that TCP Keep Alive mechanism will start after a fixed amount of idle time of no activity on the conenction and then it will send a fixed number of keep alive probes until it gets ack for those probes.
My question is whether TCP will stop sending probes upon receiving ACK for a keep alive probe or if it receives any kind of packet on the connection ?
I could not find enough documentation regarding this case on the linux man page https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html
I want to emphasize that this question is specifically about when the keep alive probes are stopped and not regarding the initial idle waiting time.

Your question is answered in the duplicate. When the connection ceases being idle, keepalive probes cease to be sent and the idle timer restarts.
